# Class Design advise (Implement with Java) - enum + inheritance

Tags: java, class, inheritance, enums

I have a design with the following classes:

```
public class Book {
  protected BookColorType color;
  public Book (BookColorType color) {
    ...
  }
}

public enum BookColorType {
  BLACK, WHITE
}

public enum ColorBookColorType {
  BLACK, WHITE, RED, BLUE, GREEN
}

public class ColorBook extends Book {
  protected ColorBookColorType color;
  public ColorBook(ColorBookColorType color) {
    // this will cause error has ColorBookColorType is not the same type as BookColorType
  }
}
```

How can I implement the above with Java and with a better class design? 
The point is Book should associate only with BookColorType while ColorBook (is a Book), and only associate with ColorBookColorType (with BLACK and WHITE duplicated).

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: What makes `ColorBook` a `Book` in that case? Whats suspicious according to you with current implementation?

Comment: You already provided a Java implementation, so what's your question here? As regards the design: it might be better to have `Book` be an interface or abstract class and another implementation/subclass like `NonColoredBook`. My problem is that I can't imagine what the color would indicate here, i.e. in what way would a BLACK book differ from a WHITE one?. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sounds like a bad design and misuse of inheritance to me.

Comment: I have not show everything of the class here. My main question is if I have a class inheritance like this, and both of them has a field "color", when color have some kind of relationship here. I would look for a better design.

Answer (score 0):

If each type of `Book` has to have its own color `Type` enumeration, make each class have knowledge of only Color Type that it needs to.
So, don't make    `BookColorType color;` an inherited field from the `Book` class but a private field of it and make `ColorBook` have its own private color type field : `ColorBookColorType  color;`.

Besides, if it makes sense to retrieve a value (String or common enum value or something else) from the both enum classes to make them interoperable in a some way, you could make them implement a specific interface.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

- You could have both your enums implement an interface, e.g. `BookColorType`.
- You would then rename your current `BookColorType` enum to something like `BWBookColorType`
- Your `Book` super class keeps the constructor and takes a `BookColorType` object as parameter
- Your `ColorBook`'s constructor invokes `super(...)`
- It can then throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the actual type of the argument is not a `ColorBookColorType`
- Note that your `ColorBook` class will not have its own field, instead it will reuse the `Book`'s field, which will be of type `BookColorType` (the type of the interface)

**Example**

```
public class Book {
    protected BookColorType color;

    public Book(BookColorType color) {

    }
}

public interface BookColorType {}

public enum BWBookColorType implements BookColorType {
    BLACK, WHITE
}

public enum ColorBookColorType implements BookColorType {
    BLACK, WHITE, RED, BLUE, GREEN
}

public class ColorBook extends Book {

    public ColorBook(BookColorType color) {
        super(color); // need to be 1st line
        if (!(color instanceof ColorBookColorType)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only colored books!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `(color instanceof ColorBookColorType)` this is quite ugly and can be solved with another interface.

Comment: @Oleg I'm a little confused by your comment... could you elaborate on why a type check is ugly, or especially the part about "solving with another interface"?

Comment: Have another interface `interface BookColorTypeColor extends BookColorType{}` the color enum can implement it and the colorbook constructor have it as parameter, this way you don't need any type checks. As to why it's ugly really?! Type checks are last resort if you don't mind them just use `Object` for everything and fill your code with type checks.

Comment: @Oleg in my opinion type checks can be necessary and I still think they are in this case. If you are overloading constructors(i.e. taking a different type parameter in the child class), you will still need to invoke the super constructor, but you won't have an actual type you can invoke it with. It's a catch 22, as there is no co-variance in method/constructor argument parametrization, only in return types.

Comment: Actually, I have some limitation on the class design and I must use "inheritance and enum" in this example (for learning purpose). I think @Mena idea is not really bad. Thanks.

Comment: @user6539552 you're welcome! Stay tuned as someone may yet have a better idea.

Comment: They are not necessary, and there is no need to overload them, with the interface I added you invoke the same super constructor in exactly the same way. There is still a problem though both with your implementation and mine that you can create `Book` with `ColorBookColorType` not sure how to solve it with the current design.

Comment: @Oleg I agree there is no need to (read, you *shouldn't*) overload the constructors in this case. In my answer, I'm actually overriding it, which gives me the possibility to late-check the actual type of the interface. If you have an interface for each class' constructor, you don't actually need interfaces as you would just as well parametrize with the two enums, hence overloading. I can't see a solution without type checking given the present design (which doesn't mean there *isn't* one, only that I haven't managed to come up with one!).

Comment: I showed you one. Once again with all the changes: new interface -  `interface BookColorTypeI extends BookColorType{}` change the second enum to `static enum ColorBookColorType implements BookColorTypeI` and change the ColorBook constructor to `public ColorBook(BookColorTypeI color) {` everything else stays the same only your `intanceof` check can be removed. The problem with preventing `new Book(ColorBookColorType.GREEN);` (should be not possible) still remains, do you have a solution for it?

Comment: @Oleg your solution improves the validation by overloading the constructors, which is acceptable as one interface extends the other (so the super type constructor invocation will compile). However as you hint, you're basically turning the problem upside-down and still requiring a type check, this time in the parent class.

Comment: I'm not overloading any constructors, there is only one constructor, I'm not turning anything upside down, I eliminated the type check, the other problem exists with both solutions and you can't solve it with a type check because you can't know what to check, it might be called directly or it might be called via super. If you still don't understand what the real problem is, forget all this comments which apparently confuse you, look at the code you posted in your answer and tell me what prevents: `new Book(ColorBookColorType.GREEN);`

Comment: Runtime checks like the one using *instanceof* should be avoided when strong typing can enforce proper object construction.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to express the constraint with strong typing, instead of idiomatic runtime checks like *instanceof*.

```
public interface Book {
  BookColor getColor();
}

public interface BookColor {

}

public enum MonoChrome implements BookColor {
  BLACK, WHITE
}

public enum Colorful implements BookColor {
  RED, BLUE, GREEN
}

public final class ColorBook implements Book {
    private final Color color;

    public ColorBook(final BookColor color) {
      super();
      this.color = Objects.requireNonNull(color);
    }
}

public final class MonoChromeBook implements Book {
    private final Color color;

    public ColorBook(final MonoChrome color) {
      super();
      this.color = Objects.requireNonNull(color);
    }
}
```

This way, **ColorBook** can have both MonoChrome and ColorFul as color. **MonoChromeBook** only accepts **MonoChrome** color.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Mena's post, I would use Generics to enforce color type:

```
public interface BookColorType {}

public class Book<C extends BookColorType> {
    protected C color;

    public Book(C color) {

    }
}

public enum BWBookColorType implements BookColorType {
    BLACK, WHITE
}

public enum ColorBookColorType implements BookColorType {
    BLACK, WHITE, RED, BLUE, GREEN
}

public class ColorBook extends Book<ColorBookColorType> {
    public ColorBook(ColorBookColorType color) {
        super(color);
    }
}

public class BWBook extends Book<BWBookColorType> {
    public BWBook(BWBookColorType color) {
        super(color);
    }
}
```